# Actualizar el valor de un campo con la informacion de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una BD sobre las carreras de la universidad en la que estoy, con registro de los alumnos. Tengo 3 tablas pero hay dos que necesito que tengan la misma informacion.

```
CREATE TABLE CARRERAS(
ID_CARRERA INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE  TEXT NOT NULL, 
ACTIVO BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE);

CREATE TABLE PERSONAS(
ID_PERSONA INT(200) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
CIUDAD VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
ACTIVO BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE);

CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS(
ID_ALUMNO INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ID_PERSONA INT,
ID_CARRERA INT NOT NULL,
CALIFICACIONES DOUBLE  NULL,
ACTIVO BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
FOREIGN KEY(ID_PERSONA) REFERENCES PERSONAS(ID_PERSONA),
FOREIGN KEY(ID_CARRERA) REFERENCES CARRERAS(ID_CARRERA));

INSERT INTO PERSONAS(NOMBRE, CIUDAD) VALUES
("ACIEN ZURUTA ROSA MARIA","TULANCINGO"),
("ALBUSAC TAMARGO DANIEL","SANTIAGO"),
("ALONSO BECERRA JOSE","PACHUCA"),
("AMAT MENA SUSANA","ACATLAN"),
("AMATE GARRIDO IRENE","TULANCINGO"),
("APARICIO GARCIA MAGDALENA","CUAUTEPEC"),
("BENAYAS PEREZ NATALIA","PACHUCA"),
("BENAYAS PEREZ NATALIA","TULANCINGO"),
("BERNABE CASANOVA FRANCISCO CESAR","CUAUTEPEC"),
("BERNAL RUIZ ENCARNACION ","TULANCINGO"),
("CACERES CONTRERAS MARIA DEL MAR","TULANCINGO"),
("CAMPOS VIQUE MARIA BELEN","PACHUCA");
```

Necesito que el ID_PERSONA de la tabla ALUMNOS tenga lo mismo que el mismo campo pero de la tabla PERSONAS. Lo intente actualizando la tabla con un inner join

```
UPDATE ALUMNOS SET ALUMNOS.ID_PERSONA = PERSONAS.ID_PERSONA 
FROM ALUMNOS INNER JOIN PERSONAS ON ALUMNOS.ID_PERSONA = PERSONAS.ID_PERSONA 
WHERE PERSONAS.ID_PERSONA = PERSONAS.ID_PERSONA;
```

Comment: Puedes dar un ejemplo de cómo esperas que se vean las tablas?

Comment: pero no puedes hacer un update si no tienes informacion en la tabla alumnos. Tampoco puedes hacer un insert en la tabla alumnos si no tienes carreras porque el campo id_carrera de la tabla alumnos es not null. Tienes inconsistencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar debes crear al menos una carrera en la tabla CARRERAS, ya que tienes definida una clave foránea (`FOREIGN KEY(ID_CARRERA) REFERENCES CARRERAS(ID_CARRERA))`) desde la tabla ALUMNOS a la tabla CARRERAS:

```
INSERT INTO CARRERAS (NOMBRE)
VALUES ("CARRERA1");
```

Una vez creada la carrera **`"1" "Carrera1"`**, realizas un INSERT a la tabla ALUMNOS utilizando un SELECT de la tabla PERSONAS de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO ALUMNOS (ID_PERSONA, ID_CARRERA, CALIFICACIONES)
SELECT ID_PERSONA, 1, NULL
FROM PERSONAS;
```

Con esto tendrías ya construida la tabla ALUMNOS con todos los ID_PERSONA de la tabla PERSONAS.

> ```
> ID_ALUMNO ID_PERSONA  ID_CARRERA  CALIFICACIONES  ACTIVO
> 1         1           1           null            1
> 2         2           1           null            1
> 3         3           1           null            1
> 4         4           1           null            1
> 5         5           1           null            1
> 6         6           1           null            1
> 7         7           1           null            1
> 8         8           1           null            1
> 9         9           1           null            1
> 10        10          1           null            1
> 11        11          1           null            1
> 12        12          1           null            1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Te falto al poner el where que compare una tabla con la otra, estabas poniendo : Where 1eratabla.id = 1eraTabla.id

```
UPDATE ALUMNOS SET ALUMNOS.ID_PERSONA = PERSONAS.ID_PERSONA 
FROM ALUMNOS INNER JOIN PERSONAS ON ALUMNOS.ID_PERSONA = PERSONAS.ID_PERSONA 
WHERE PERSONAS.ID_PERSONA = ALUMNOS.ID_PERSONA;
```

Cabe recalcar que si tu tabla donde pasarás la información tiene el **Identify ON Autogenerado** no te dejará cambiar ese registro